# css sibling outside parent combinator

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <a class="_link _spec nta">Link one</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="_link _spec">Link two</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to select the second anchor element but, I'm having problem.
All I want is to select it based on the first anchor if it contains .nta class

```
._spec.nta + a { color:red; }
```

I tried this but it works only if the element is next to it.

Comment: CSS has no parent selector. You can target just siblings or children. Remove `div`s or add classes to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have two options:

1. Move class names from a element to div element. It would look like this:

```css
.nta + ._spec{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
  <div class="main">
       <div class="_spec nta">
           <a class="_link">Link one</a>
       </div>
       <div class="_spec">
           <a class="_link">Link two</a>
       </div>
</div>
```

2. Using :not() property:

```css
 ._link._spec:not(.nta) {
        color: red;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="main">
      <div>
        <a class="_link _spec nta">Link one</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a class="_link _spec">Link two</a>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Good luck!